# Get a variable from an external Class

Tags: flash, class, properties, external

I'm using an external class to draw an object in my Flash movie but I need to get some variables from the Class as well.

I want to put the variable `persPoints[0].x` into a variable in my main document called `newvar` for example.

This is the part of the External Class I'm using

```
class Shape {

function set2DTo3D():Void {
        var persPoints:Array = new Array();
        for (var i:Number = 0; i < this.pointsArray.length; i++) {
            persPoints[i] = new Object();
            this.perspectief = this.scaleValue / (this.scaleValue - this.pointsArray[i].z);
            persPoints[i].x = this.pointsArray[i].x * this.perspectief;
            persPoints[i].y = this.pointsArray[i].y * this.perspectief;
        }
        this.draw(persPoints);
    }
}
```

And somehow I will need to get that variable into my `onEnterFrame` function of my `.fla` below.

```
var kubusMC:MovieClip = this.createEmptyMovieClip("kubusMC", 0);
kubusMC._x = Stage.width/2;//plaats de mc in het midden
kubusMC._y = Stage.height/2;

var kubus:Shape = new Shape(punten, kubusMC, 300, 1, 0x222222, 85);


this.onEnterFrame = function() {


}
```

But how?

Answer (score 0):

The only change you need to make, from what I can see, is to move the `persPoints` array out  of the `set2DTo3D` function to make it a member of your class instance.  Like so:

```
class Shape {

    var persPoints:Array = new Array();

    function set2DTo3D():Void 
    { 
        for (var i:Number = 0; i < this.pointsArray.length; i++) 
        { 
            persPoints[i] = new Object(); 
            this.perspectief = this.scaleValue / (this.scaleValue - this.pointsArray[i].z);
            persPoints[i].x = this.pointsArray[i].x * this.perspectief; 
            persPoints[i].y = this.pointsArray[i].y * this.perspectief; 
        } 

        this.draw(persPoints); 
    } 
}
```

Now that `persPoints` is available as an instance member, you can access it in your onEnterFrame function:

```
var kubusMC:MovieClip = this.createEmptyMovieClip("kubusMC", 0); kubusMC._x = Stage.width/2;//plaats de mc in het midden kubusMC._y = Stage.height/2;

var kubus:Shape = new Shape(punten, kubusMC, 300, 1, 0x222222, 85);

this.onEnterFrame = function() 
{
    var value = kubus.persPoints[0].x;

    trace("x value of kubus.persPoints[0]: " + value);
}
```

Comment: What can I say, thanx a thousand times :)